# Как соединить массивы?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, по задаче:

Есть три массива, первый это время, тут главное hours, (car, bike - всегда нули).
Второй и третий массив это данные которые приходят порознь, два сразу только для примера.

`let hours = [
    {0: "hour":0, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {1: "hour":1, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {2: "hour":2, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {3: "hour":3, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {4: "hour":4, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {5: "hour":5, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {6: "hour":6, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {7: "hour":7, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
];`

let first = [
    {0: "hour":5, 'car':10, 'bike': 10},
    {1: "hour":8, 'car':20, 'bike': 0},
    {2: "hour":9, 'car':30, 'bike': 0},
    {3: "hour":10, 'car':40, 'bike': 0},
];

let second = [
    {0: "hour":0, 'car':11, 'bike': 12},
    {1: "hour":7, 'car':15, 'bike': 25},
    {2: "hour":8, 'car':20, 'bike': 30},
    {3: "hour":9, 'car':10, 'bike': 30},
    {4: "hour":10, 'car':120, 'bike': 140},
];

Как можно сделать так чтобы я мог соединять массив времени с другим массивом и заменять недостающие данные, к примеру:

hours + first, должно выйти:

`first = [
    // в first отсутствует hour:0,1,2,3,4, значит нужно добавить с массива hours
    {0: "hour":0, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {1: "hour":1, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {2: "hour":2, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {3: "hour":3, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {4: "hour":4, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    // дальше добавляем то что было в first
    {5: "hour":5, 'car':10, 'bike': 10},
    //  с hours, потому что в first нету 6,7
    {6: "hour":6, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {7: "hour":7, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {8: "hour":8, 'car':20, 'bike': 0},
    {9: "hour":9, 'car':30, 'bike': 0},
    {10: "hour":10, 'car':40, 'bike': 0},
];`

hours + second:

second = [
    // Данные с second
    {0: "hour":0, 'car':11, 'bike': 12},
    // Данные с hours
    {1: "hour":1, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {2: "hour":2, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {3: "hour":3, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {4: "hour":4, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {5: "hour":5, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {6: "hour":6, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    // Данные с second должны затереть данные с нулями из hours
    {7: "hour":7, 'car':15, 'bike': 25},
    {8: "hour":8, 'car':20, 'bike': 30},
    {9: "hour":9, 'car':10, 'bike': 30},
    {10: "hour":10, 'car':120, 'bike': 140},
];

Грубо говоря соеденить два массива. Честно, много перепробовал, но результата;

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: "много перепробовал" - где?

Comment: @Igor, у меня ничего не вышло, а переносить ту "дичь" что я написал смысла мало.

Comment: У Вас ничего не вышло с двумя циклами - один в другом?

Comment: @Igor второй массив просто записывается вконец первого.

Comment: рекомендую также не забывать про lodash - https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let hours = [
  {"hour":1, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":0, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":2, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":3, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":4, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":5, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":6, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":7, 'car':0, 'bike': 0}
]

let first = [
  {"hour":5, 'car':10, 'bike': 10},
  {"hour":8, 'car':20, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":9, 'car':30, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":10, 'car':40, 'bike': 0}
]

let second = [
  {"hour":0, 'car':11, 'bike': 12},
  {"hour":7, 'car':15, 'bike': 25},
  {"hour":8, 'car':20, 'bike': 30},
  {"hour":9, 'car':10, 'bike': 30},
  {"hour":10, 'car':120, 'bike': 140}
]

console.log(combine(hours, first));
console.log(combine(hours, second));

function combine(array1, array2){

  var map1 = array1.reduce((prev, item) => {
    prev[item.hour] = item;
    return prev;
  }, {});

  var map2 = array2.reduce((prev, item) => {
    prev[item.hour] = item;
    return prev;
  }, {})

  for (var key in map2){
    map1[key] = map2[key]
  }

  var result = []
  for (var key in map1){
    result.push(map1[key])
  }

  return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю насколько это правильно, но вот что у меня получилось:

```js
let hours = [
  {"hour":1, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":0, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":2, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":3, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":4, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":5, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":6, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":7, 'car':0, 'bike': 0}
]

let first = [
  {"hour":5, 'car':10, 'bike': 10},
  {"hour":8, 'car':20, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":9, 'car':30, 'bike': 0},
  {"hour":10, 'car':40, 'bike': 0}
]

let second = [
  {"hour":0, 'car':11, 'bike': 12},
  {"hour":7, 'car':15, 'bike': 25},
  {"hour":8, 'car':20, 'bike': 30},
  {"hour":9, 'car':10, 'bike': 30},
  {"hour":10, 'car':120, 'bike': 140}
]

        function add(left, right) {
            for (let i = 0; i < left.length; i++) {
                if (left[i].hour != right[i].hour) {
                    right.splice([i], 0, left[i]);
                }
            }

        }

        add(hours, first);
        add(hours, second);


        console.log(first);
        console.log(second);
```

Comment: @Spomni Ну да, при других условиях мое решение посыпется)

Comment: Если массив `left` не имеет пропусков по значению `hour`, то ваше решение выглядит проще моего. И будем надеяться, что элементы в массивы добавляются не в произвольном порядке, а упорядочены по полю `hour`. )

Answer (score 0):

```js
let hours = [
    {"hour":0, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {"hour":1, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {"hour":2, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {"hour":3, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {"hour":4, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {"hour":5, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {"hour":6, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
    {"hour":7, 'car':0, 'bike': 0},
];



let first = [
    {"hour":5, 'car':10, 'bike': 10},
    {"hour":8, 'car':20, 'bike': 0},
    {"hour":9, 'car':30, 'bike': 0},
    {"hour":10, 'car':40, 'bike': 0},
];



let second = [
    {"hour":0, 'car':11, 'bike': 12},
    {"hour":7, 'car':15, 'bike': 25},
    {"hour":8, 'car':20, 'bike': 30},
    {"hour":9, 'car':10, 'bike': 30},
    {"hour":10, 'car':120, 'bike': 140},
];

hours.push(...second)
console.log(hours);
```

Comment: Что значат три точки?

Comment: В данном случае выражение `...second` разбивает массив `second` на его елементы. Это решение просто склеивает два массива. Кажется, вам нужно было что-то другое.